# Android - onActivityResult not called when opening another activity before finish the first one

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity, onactivityresult

I have `ActivityA` from where I open another activity:

```
val intent = Intent(this, ActivityC::class.java)
startActivityForResult(intent,  99)
```

When I finish `ActivityC` as expected, I get the callback in `onActivityResult` of `ActivityA`.

The problem is that if I open another activity from `ActivityA` like:

```
startActivity(Intent(this, ActivityB::class.java))
```

before calling `finish()` in `ActivityC`, and then do `finish()` in `ActivityC` I don't get the callback.

Is there any workaround about this?

**CODE**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        findViewById<TextView>(R.id.clickme).setOnClickListener {
            startActivityForResult(Intent(this, MainActivity2::class.java), 99)

            Handler().postDelayed({
                startActivity(Intent(this, MainActivity3::class.java))
            }, 1000)
        }
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        System.out.println("Came to onActivityResult")
    }
}
```

Activity2:

```
class MainActivity2 : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2)

        Handler().postDelayed({
            setResult(RESULT_OK)
            finish()
        }, 2000)
    }
}
```

Removing the call:

```
startActivity(Intent(this, MainActivity3::class.java))
```

Will trigger the `onActivityResult` as expected.

Comment: please share your code, there might be some mistake in code...

Comment: @hafiza I think it's not a code mistake. You can try with the example above.

Comment: I don't think you're intended to do this. An Activity shouldn't be starting multiple other Activities simultaneously. It's going to open you up to all kinds of possible bugs with the order of the task stack. Open the second activity and pass it an extra that can tell it if it should open another activity after itself. That way, each Activity has a clear parent and child, and the task stack is kept orderly.

Comment: This seems to be answered here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/how-to-manage-startactivityforresult-on-android